# Two definitions of the natural logarithm

Tags: functions, logarithms, definition

Apart from the definition involving integration, I would like to check whether the following definitions of the $\ln$ function are :

1. accurate
2. equivalent

Def 1 .$$\begin{cases} (\forall x, y \in (0,+\infty)) \quad f(xy) = f(x)+f(y) \\ f \text{ is differentiable at 1 with } f'(1)=1 \end{cases}$$

Def 2
$$ \begin{cases} f \text{ is differentiable on } (0,+\infty) \text{ with } f'(x) = \dfrac 1x \text{ for all } x \in (0,+\infty) \\
f(1)=0\end{cases}$$

Comment: The first line of Def 1 seems to suggest $f(x)=k \log_e(x)$ when $x \gt 0$ and the second leads to $k=1$.  The first line of Def 2 seems to suggest  $f(x)=c+  \log_e(x)$ when $x \gt 0$ and the second leads to $c=0$.  So I do not see any issues here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases, my answer is: it is fine, as long as you prove that such a function exists. Assuming that, yes, these definitions are equivalent to $\log(x)=\int_1^x\frac{\mathrm dt}t$.

Comment: Do you mean that the existence can only be justified through the integral definition ? (fundamental theoroem of calculus)

Comment: In the case of the second definition, using the fundamental theorem of Calculus end the simplest way. Or you could use a theorem about the existence and unicity of solutions of differentiable equations.